# Issue with node fs.readFileSync() and cron

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, path, cron

I'm trying to run a node script with Crone and even though I think I'm using the absolute path in every step of the way, I am still getting a "no such file or directory" when trying to read a JSON file while running the script from Cron.

The interesting thing is that everything works fine when I run it from the shell!

```
[/]$ /usr/local/bin/node /root/Main/email.js
```

^^ This works fine!

However when I run with crontab like this:

```
0,29 * * * * /usr/local/bin/node /root/Main/email.js
```

I get this printed to the log:

```
fs.js:438
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'root/Main/email.json'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:438:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:289:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/Main/email.js:11:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

The line of code on my node sketch that is throwing the error is this one:

```
var file = fs.readFileSync('root/Main/email.json', 'utf8')
```

What am I missing? Isn't this the absolute path? Why is it only working directly from the shell!

Comment: You're missing a slash ("/") before your path. Change the line causing the error to `var file = fs.readFileSync('/root/Main/email.json', 'utf8');`

Comment: That worked! I'm still wondering why it still works on the shell even with the "wrong" path

Comment: Well, without a leading slash, the path is interpreted as relative to the current directory. If your prompt looks like `[/]$`, then you're probably already in the top-level directory, and so everything works well.

Comment: Cool! Thank you! =)